# Hotkey to toggle spelling check in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word, hotkeys, spell-check

I need to switch the checking quickly since I often work with Vietnamese and English files.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution #1 (recommened)

source https://superuser.com/a/763396/34893

> The easiest way is setting the language by pressing ctrl+A (or only
>   the words in that language) then click the language button in the
>   status bar > Mark selected text as and select the correct language
>
> ...

### Solution #2

source https://superuser.com/a/763425/34893

> You can use the macro function. Select Developer tab > Record Macro.
>   Choose any name you like and assign it to a button or keyboard
>   shortcut. After that disable spell check/grammar check as normal and
>   select stop recoding in macro group from Developer tab. Record another
>   macro to enable the check again.
>
> ...

Comment: I can't find the "Language" button in the status bar. There is a checkbox next to the "Language" setting in the popup list. Do you have to have multiple languages configured in the operating system?

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>F7</kbd>
 -   Commonly used to spell check and grammar check a document in Microsoft programs such as Microsoft Word, Outlook, etc.
 -   <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> runs a Thesaurus check on the word highlighted.
 -   it also turns on Caret browsing in Mozilla Firefox.
From [ComputerHope](http://www.computerhope.com/shortcut/word.htm)
And this [Shortcuts lists](http://www.helpwithpcs.com/tipsandtricks/keyboard_shortcuts_microsoft_word.htm)
This free program 'Autohotkey' lets you set & reset keys to [your own selection](http://www.autohotkey.com/)
TinySpell has an on/off [hotkey setting](http://tinyspell.numerit.com/)
 It is very easy to use, it does not come with Vietnamese but you are able to add words to the program and in the paid version you can link to web sites to check spelling - there is a free trial period. As you can link to a website you maybe able to link to a program file or to a home made html list on your own machine.

Hope this helps

Comment: Nice hotkeys. Though, I need to turn on/off the checker, nay idea?

Comment: @Nam Gi VU have added to answer 'tinyspell'

Comment: I need to toggle on/off the microsoft-word spell checker my friend...

Comment: @Nam Gi VU sorry tiny does work on word and almost everything else, will keep looking-could you turn off the word english dic and use tiny on the fly for the english?